# Can I change text in MS Word using python-docx, without losing characteristics?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I now have a English word document in MS Word and I want to change its texts into Chinese using python. I've been using Python 3.4 and installed python-docx. Here's my code:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document(*some MS Word file*)
# I only change the texts of the first two paragraphs
document.paragraphs[0].text = '带有消毒模式的地板清洁机'
document.paragraphs[1].text = '背景'
document.save(*save_file_path*)
```

The first two lines did turn into Chinese characters, but characteristics like font and bold are all gone:
[image: the original file looks like this]

[image: and the new file looks like this]

Is there anyway I could alter text without losing the original characteristics?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the characteristics are applied. There is a thing called the *style hierarchy*, and text characteristics can be applied anywhere from directly to a run of text, a style, or a document default, and levels in-between.

There are two main classes of characteristic: paragraph properties and run properties. Paragraph properties are things like justification, space before and after, etc. Everything having to do with character-level formatting, like size, typeface, color, subscript, italic, bold, etc. is a run property, also loosely known as a *font*.

So if you want to preserve the font of a run of text, you need to operate at the run level. An operation like this will preserve font formatting:

```
run.text = "New text"
```

An operation like this will preserve paragraph formatting, but remove any character level formatting not applied by the paragraph style:

```
paragraph.text = "New paragraph text"
```

You'll need to decide for your application whether you modify individual runs (which may be tricky to identify) or whether you work perhaps with distinct paragraphs and apply different styles to each. I recommend the latter. So in your example, "FLOOR CLEANING MACHINE ...", "BACKGROUND", and "[0001]..." would each become distinct paragraphs. In your screenshot they appear as separate runs in a single paragraph, separated by a line break.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the style of the existing paragraphs and apply it to your new paragraphs - beware that the existing paragraphs **might** specify a font that does not support Chinese.

Comment: Yes I'm aware... I'm reading [documentation of python-docx](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Font) here. It seems a little bit too many characteristics, is it not? Do I have to get all of them to keep the style?

Comment: @joewong - If I recall correctly you can get the style, copy it as a style object and then apply it to the new paragraph. Haven't had a chance to test though.